# Material UI define a new property on palette's primary object with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to play around with MUI v5 custome theme to get it working in my project, so far i am able to customize my theme as per my needs, but now the issue is that i need to add a new property to my primary object defined inside palette, by default each object in paletter is supposed to have 4 main properties  -

```
light?: string;
  main: string;
  dark?: string;
  contrastText?: string;
```

but what if i want to add a new property to it like "magic" ?

theme.ts

```
import { createTheme, Theme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { brown, red } from "@mui/material/colors";

declare module "@mui/material/styles/createPalette" {
  interface Palette {
    brown: PaletteColor;
  }

  interface PaletteOptions {
    brown: PaletteColorOptions;
  }
}

declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  // fix the type error when referencing the Theme object in your styled component
  interface Theme {
    myField?: {
      myNestedField?: string;
    };
  }
  // fix the type error when calling `createTheme()` with a custom theme option
  interface ThemeOptions {
    myField?: {
      myNestedField: {
        margin?: string;
      };
    };
  }
}

export const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#ffffff",
      magic:'#000000 ///throws error - 
    },
    brown: {
      main: brown[300],
    },
  },
  myField: {
    myNestedField: { margin: "10px 5px" },
  },
});
```

so when i define "magic" inside parimary i get the error

> Type '{ main: string; magic: string; }' is not assignable to type
> 'PaletteColorOptions | undefined'.   Object literal may only specify
> known properties, and 'magic' does not exist in type
> 'PaletteColorOptions'.

Answer (score 2):

`PaletteColorOptions` is a `type` – not an `interface` so we can't use [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) on it. But luckily it's made up of the composition of two interfaces: `type PaletteColorOptions = SimplePaletteColorOptions | ColorPartial`. So we can augment interface `SimplePaletteColorOptions` like so:

```js
declare module '@mui/material/styles/createPalette' {
  interface SimplePaletteColorOptions {
    magic: string
  }
}
```